# kivymd crushes on main.kv

Tags: android, kivymd

i checked logs but there was no error
app compiled with buildozer, python 3.11 ,kivy,kivymd,plyer
i gave permission to gps in buildozer.spec and imported all modules but it still crash
i can give you logs but there is no errors
when i run this my app on laptop it works and dont crash

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from plyer import gps
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.utils import platform
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivymd.uix.toolbar import MDTopAppBar
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
kv='''
MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    MDTopAppBar:
        title: "Hello world!" 
        right_action_items: [["dots-vertical", lambda x: app.callback()]]
    MDLabel:
        text: app.gps_status
        halign: "center"
    MDLabel:
        text: app.gps_location
        halign: "center"
    MDSwitch:
        active: False 
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
        width: dp(45)
        on_active: app.start(*args)
'''

class Main(MDApp):
    gps_location = StringProperty()
    gps_status = StringProperty()
    def request_android_permissions(self):
        import android
        from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
        def callback(permissions, results):
            droid = android.Android()
            if all([res for res in results]):
                droid.makeToast("callback. All permissions granted.")
            else:
                droid.makeToast("callback. Some permissions refused.")
                
        request_permissions([Permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                Permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION], callback)
    def build(self):
        try:
                    gps.configure(on_location=self.on_location)
        except NotImplementedError:
                    self.gps_status = 'GPS is not implemented for your platform'
        if platform == "android":
            self.request_android_permissions()
            gps.configure(on_location=self.on_location)
        return Builder.load_string(kv)
    def on_location(self, **kwargs):
        self.gps_location = '\n'.join([
        '{}={}'.format(k, v) for k, v in kwargs.items()])   
    def start(self, minTime, minDistance):
        gps.start(minTime, minDistance) 
        droid.makeToast("programm started")
    def stop(self):
        droid.makeToast("programm stopped")
        gps.stop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main().run()
```

Comment: someone help pls